# jquery how to sum input field

Tags: jquery

```
Hi everyone i need some help: i try to sum input field in my html but the results must be in a different place in table:
```

with this code it works but the total is not where i want. It must be connection with col number and total but i do not know how to do it. In WATERMELON COLUMN I WANT TWO TOTALS THE FIRST BUT THE SECOND IS NOT WORKING. That is a small part of table the real one is very big and have two or more totals in one column.
    `http://jsfiddle.net/SXF8H/123/`

Comment: Please post your code here and don't try and sidestep the rule of posting your code here when linking to jsFiddle.net.

Answer (score 1):

You are adding `0` and `"40"` to each other. Adding a string is concatenation, regardless of that string being numeric. This is why you see `040`, then `04040` and so on.

Use `parseInt( _ , 10)` to convert your string to a number. Then you'll be working with the addition you're expecting.